# How do you add a new MediaType to the MediaTypeFormatters used by ASP.Net WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net WebAPI project that will be returning JSON, but specifically HAL+JSON.  I know I can write a custom MediaTypeFormatter to do this, but I plan on returning the same HAL formatted response even if you ask for plain JSON, so my question is:

Rather than writing a new MediaTypeFormatter for HAL+JSON, can I add a new media type ("application/hal+json") to the list of media types that the default WebAPI JsonMediaTypeFormatter recognizes?

Answer (score 4):

Think I found my answer.  In Global.asax:Application_Start(), I can do this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/hal+json"));
```

Comment: Savior!! found this after few hours